# Adding supporting libraries to NuGet package without adding as references

Tags: nuget

I have a group of DLLs: some are meant to be directly referenced by the project and others are just supporting those DLLs and aren't meant for direct interaction. I know how to add files to be project references for NuGet: put them in the lib folder. But how do I get DLLs to be around to get picked up during builds but not be project references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pranavkm on the NuGet CodePlex discussions pointed me here:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Explicit_Assembly_References

Comment: For an example of how this is done in practice, see the [xunit.core.nuspec](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core.nuspec) file -- they add several files using the `<file>` element and then explicitly specify which DLL is to be referenced in the project using the `<references>` element.